# Spring IoC: identifier per request

Tags: spring, spring-ioc

I've created this bean in order to get a `Supplier<String>`:

```
@Bean
public Supplier<String> auditIdSupplier() {
    return () -> String.join(
        "-",
        "KEY",
        UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    );
}
```

As you can see, it's intented to only generate an straightforward identifier string.

Each time, it's called, a new identifier is supplied.

I'd like to change this behavior, in order to get the same generated identifier inside request scope. I mean, first time a request is reached, a new indentifier is generated. From then on, next calls no this `Supplier` has to return the first generated indentifier inside request scope.

Any ideas?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is to use a `RequestScope` bean which wraps this functionality. Have you considered that already?

Comment: Maybe the spring sleuth project can help you. They already have a traceId and a spanId. If you manage to re-use them, you might not need to track your requests manually.

Answer (score 0):

As it was written in commentary, maybe something like below will work:

```
@Bean
@RequestScope
public Supplier<String> auditIdSupplier() {
    String val = String.join("-","KEY",UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    return () -> val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a request scoped bean

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    public String myRequestScopedIdentifyer(NativeWebRequest httpRequest) {
        // You don't need request as parameter here, but you can inject it this way if you need request context

        return String.join(
          "-",
          "KEY",
          UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }
```

And then inject it where appropriate with either field injection

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

    @Autowired 
    @Qualifier("myRequestScopedIdentifyer")
    private String identifier
```

or object factory

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

    public MyClass(@Qualifier("myRequestScopedIdentifyer") ObjectFactory<String> identifyerProvider) {
        this.identifyerProvider= identifyerProvider;
    }


    private final ObjectFactory<String> identifyerProvider;

    public void someMethod() {
        String requestScopedId = identifyerProvider.getObject();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version:

```
@Component
@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)
public class AuditIdPerRequest {
   private String key;

   @PostConstruct 
   public void calculateKey() {
      this.key = String.join(
        "-",
        "KEY",
        UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    );
   }

   public String getAuditId() {
      return this.key;
   }  
}
```